Paper request: Graev's classification of SU(2,2) irreducible unitary representations
I am interested in Graev's paper in "M. L. Graev:Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR,98, 517 (1954); Amer. Math. Soc. Transl.,66, 1 (1968)." in which the irreducible unitary representations of SU(2,2) are classified. An example for an (also quite old) article that references Graev is Esteve and Sona - Conformal group in Minkowsky space. Unitary irreducible representations, which presumably already discusses some of its content.
The original from 1954 is probably in Russian, I would prefer a translated version (like the referenced one from 1968) or a source that reviews its content. However, I guess finding the Russian version would also be a start.

Just to make sure, is the paper you're referencing "Principal series of unitary representations of real forms of the complex unimodular group" (MR0066389)?

Another reference for the same topic is "Langlands Classification and Unitary Dual of SU(2,2)", MR0789291  (Lectures in Applied Math. 21, 1985).

@LSpice The one in AMS Transl 66 is "Unitary representations of real simple Lie groups". This is a much longer paper (62 pages).

The original Russian version can be found in the digitized archives of Doklady. It's 4 pages starting from here.

Thank you everyone for helping, I just have received the English translation from American Math. Soc. Transl. 66, which is as Dave Benson writes, much longer than the original four pages.

As a service to posterity, here is a transcription (pdf, tex) of the original article and its translation (pdf, tex) into English, produced with AI assistance.

Wow, thank you so much!
